# PullMessages() always return "InvalidArgVal"

Tags: events, onvif

First I create a PullPoint Subscription and then Subscribe but when i send to the uri in the response the PullMessages() command i always get the same response. Can you see what is the problem ?

My PullMessages() request -

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true"><wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsu:Id="Id"><wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password=Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">cCMdBA6WisDrtJItFsSEbiQnifc=</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce>HYwnVsldpikr+h8zuGsT9QTw8ec=</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2015-10-21T12:59:09Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>
<wsa5:Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/PullPointSubscription/PullMessagesRequest</wsa5:Action></SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body><tev:PullMessages><tev:Timeout>PT00H00M05S</tev:Timeout>
<tev:MessageLimit>1</tev:MessageLimit></tev:PullMessages>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Response from device -

```
<s:Header>
<wsa:Action>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</wsa:Action></s:Header>
<s:Body><s:Fault><s:Code><s:Value>env:Sender</s:Value>
<s:Subcode><s:Value>ter:InvalidArgVal</s:Value></s:Subcode></s:Code>
<s:Reason><s:Text xml:lang="en">Argument Value Invalid</s:Text></s:Reason>
<s:Node>http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/node/ultimateReceiver</s:Node>
<s:Role>http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/role/ultimateReceiver</s:Role>
<s:Detail><wsrf-r:ResourceUnknownFault><wsrf-bf:Timestamp>2015-10-21T12:58:50.937248Z</wsrf-bf:Timestamp></wsrf-r:ResourceUnknownFault></s:Detail>
</s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

P.S. - if you need more information don't hesitate to ask

Comment: are you using c# code?

Comment: Try other parameters. PT00H00M05S is PT5S, and many cameras have intervals for MessageLimit, try other value.

Comment: My code is c++...the problem was i did not filled the 'to' attribute in the header...thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i did not filled the 'to' attribute in the header.

I found that the best way is to watch packets from "Onvif device manager"
in wireshark to see if something does not match in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be because your subscription duration gets expired.

How to check this:
In wireshark, see few initial first PullMessage requests are successfully returned or timed out. (you can also check responses by putting a print in PullMessage response object). 
Keep track of Termination Time parameter provided in response of PullMessage.
And later on when you send request, you may be sending it to expired subscription manager, so camera gives you "InvalidArg".

How to solve this:
Remember, PullMessage description in wsdl document does not say that camera has to renew the subscription everytime when PullMessage is received.
Most of Axis Cameras never renew it. As they strictly follow onvif standard.
So, what you can do is you can use the subscription notification RENEW method. You can keep a timer which is less than PullPointSubscription duration. And at expiration of this timer, you can send RENEW request of BaseNotification method. This will renew the subscription duration of the PullPoint subscription manager.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was caused by not fully filled header of the request, which is similar to ArielY's case.

The working request must look similar to this:

```xml
POST /onvif/services HTTP/1.1
Host: >IpAddress<
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 930

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/PullPointSubscription/PullMessagesRequest</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:27577591-b1f2-4750-a705-5036364fefc9</a:MessageID>
    <Security>...</Security>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <SubscriptionId a:IsReferenceParameter="true" xmlns="http://www.axis.com/2009/event" xmlns:dom0="http://www.axis.com/2009/event">41</SubscriptionId>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://>IpAddress</onvif/services</a:To>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <PullMessages xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl">
      <Timeout>PT20S</Timeout>
      <MessageLimit>2</MessageLimit>
    </PullMessages>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

It seems that only thing that may be omitted is the ReplyTo tag.
At first I ommited Action, MessageId, ReplyTo, and SubscriptionId.

Edit: With some cameras only SubscriptionId must be present.